# Referencing non-parameter entries in config.yml

Tags: symfony, reference, yaml, config

I have quite extensive config .yml files and I'd like to refer to various settings there:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_USER: ROLE_ADMIN

easy_admin:
    entities:
        Group:
            form:
                fields:
                    - 
                      property: 'roles' 
                      type: choice
                      type_options: 
                          expanded: true
                          multiple: true
                          choices: "%security.role_hierarchy%"
```

Of course the last line doesn't work because `%security.role_hierarchy%` refers to `parameters.security.role_hierarchy`. Is there any valid way to reference `security.role_hierarchy` in `easy_admin` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid way to do that in YAML is using the standard feature [anchors and aliases](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#iid2765878). Anchors (that what is going to be referenced) are indicated by `&<name>` and alias (one or more points where the anchor is referenced) are indicated by '*`:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy: &hr1
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_USER: ROLE_ADMIN

easy_admin:
    entities:
        Group:
            form:
                fields:
                    -
                      property: 'roles'
                      type: choice
                      type_options:
                          expanded: true
                          multiple: true
                          choices: *hr1
```

The value for the mapping entry `choices`, when retrieved will be the mapping:

```
ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
ROLE_SUPER_USER: ROLE_ADMIN
```

(translated to the hash or dictionary like object of the programming language the YAML parser is written in), and is the same entity as the value for the key `role_hierarchy`.

Comment: It works in a simplified case I presented here. But what if the config is distributed among many files and each of them defines security.role_hierarchy? Your solution seems to reference to a point in code not the value of security.role_hierarchy merged by Symfony.

Still, as I said, your solution does answer the question I asked and I'll use it in other cases. So, thanks a lot :)  I'm going to accept it and ask another question, linking here.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361467/referencing-non-parameter-entries-in-distributed-config-yml

Comment: @Forseti YAML can only do these references within a document, and not even when there are multiple documents in a file. For something like that the program loading the documents needs to take care, and it has to be different syntax than the YAML anchor/aliases one, as all parsers I know blow up on aliases that have no previous anchor in the file. So in your case it is up to symfony2, but I cannot help you there.