# Referencing non-parameter entries in distributed config.yml

Tags: symfony, reference, yaml, config

This is follow-up of [Referencing non-parameter entries in config.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356786/referencing-non-parameter-entries-in-config-yml) question I asked yesterday.

Suppose we have more complicated case where there is a .yml config file for each entity. In each there is security.role_hierarchy setting with a hierarchy of roles pertaining to that entity. Like so:

```
#user.yml
security:
    role_hierarchy: &srh
        ROLE_USER_SHOW: ~
        ROLE_USER_LIST: ~
        ROLE_USER_NEW: ~
        ROLE_USER_EDIT_OWN: ~
        ROLE_USER_EDIT: ROLE_USER_EDIT_OWN
        ROLE_USER_SOFTDELETE_OWN: ~
        ROLE_USER_SOFTDELETE: ROLE_USER_SOFTDELETE_OWN
        ROLE_USER_DELETE: ~
        ROLE_USER_FLAG: ~
        ROLE_USER_ALL:
            - ROLE_USER_SHOW
            - ROLE_USER_LIST
            - ROLE_USER_NEW
            - ROLE_USER_EDIT
            - ROLE_USER_DELETE
            - ROLE_USER_SOFTDELETE
            - ROLE_USER_FLAG

#group.yml
security:
    role_hierarchy: &srh
        ROLE_GROUP_SHOW: ~
        ROLE_GROUP_LIST: ~
        ROLE_GROUP_NEW: ~
        ROLE_GROUP_EDIT: ~
        ROLE_GROUP_DELETE: ~
        ROLE_GROUP_ALL:
            - ROLE_GROUP_SHOW
            - ROLE_GROUP_LIST
            - ROLE_GROUP_NEW
            - ROLE_GROUP_EDIT
            - ROLE_GROUP_DELETE

easy_admin:
    entities:
        Group:
            form:
                fields:
                    - 
                      property: 'roles' 
                      type: choice
                      type_options: 
                          expanded: true
                          multiple: true
                          choices: *srh
```

But presented solution only links `choices` to `security.role_hierarchy` in `group.yml` and so it references only `ROLE_GROUP_*` roles.
I'd like `choices` to be supplied with merged value of `security.role_hierarchy` so that it had `ROLES_USER_*`, `ROLES_GROUP_*` and all the other defined roles.

Is this possible?

Comment: `&` and `*` at the beginning of a scalar are reserved for anchors and aliases in YAML and these have to occur in the same document (there can be multiple documents in a file, but each file is at least one YAML document). For most YAML parsers you cannot even find an element by anchor name (the exception being my ruamel.yaml parser for Python when running in round_trip mode). symfony2 cannot resolve this for you using this syntax, but maybe it has some other way (i.e. syntax) of cross-referencing data from different YAML documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to do it myself.
As @Anthon said, `&` and `*` are of no use here. We must do it through Symfony. Here is how:

I use `security.role_hierarchy` as mergable point of defining security hierarchy - and a list of roles used in application. I leave choice field with undefined choices, like so:

```
            - 
              property: 'roles' 
              type: choice
              type_options: 
                  expanded: true
                  multiple: true
```

Then I use a method in controller to set up the choices:

```
// AppBundle/Controller/AdminController.php
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $choices = [];$preferred = [];
    $vals = array_keys($this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles'));
    $choices = $vals;
    // actually there is some beautifying of $choices but it's not that important
    // get $formBuilder and...
    $formBuilder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, ['choices'=>array_combine($choices, $vals), 'multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>false]);
    return $formBuilder;
}
```

I left off `$formBuilder` creation because I did it in a way suitable for EasyAdmin so in other case there would be another ways to do it.

There could be another way to do it but it's messy: get the `security.role_hierarchy` in the controller, process it as you like and then assign it to Twig global variable:

```
// AppBundle/Controller/AdminController.php
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $vals = array_keys($this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles'));
    $this->container->get('twig')->addGlobal("_security_roles", $vals);
    // ...
}
```

Then update appropriate Twig template.

But I don't like needless globals so haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: Glad you found a way to get this done, sorry I couldn't be of more help